# Auto Publicação Wordpress c#

Tags: c#, wordpress, variáveis

Quero que uma aplicação em C# faça uma postagem num blog WordPress. O titulo do post seria o valor da variável `title` e o artigo seria a variável `html`. Como consigo isso?

*Obs: Projeto em console.*

Comment: Olá, Raul. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Será mais fácil conseguir ajuda se postar o código que você já fez ou o que já tentou fazer, além do erro que está obtendo, ao invés de esperar que alguém faça o código do zero.  Abraço!

Comment: E quanto à pergunta ter sido fechada, ela não é fora de escopo, ampla ou "não clara". Tudo o que precisa para respondê-la é um método com dois parâmetros que faz uma chamada à API do Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve utilizar [WordPress’ XML-RPC interface](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support). Tem muitos exemplos e artigos sobre ela que você pode utilizar ([examplo](http://www.xml-rpc.net/)).

Comment: Sim, mas por exemplo, como se faz isto?Comecei agora em C#...

Comment: bom primeiro é de suma importância que você vá atras um pouco leia a documentação e busque um pouco a forma de consumir isto. Mas se tiver paciência colocarei um exemplo tipo faça por mim para ficar mais fácil para você implementar sem precisar estudar um pouco

Comment: O StackOverflow não é um site para requisição de soluções, da maneira que você solicitou. Leia mais em pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask e pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Eu não quero que alguém faça isto pra mim,quero saber como faz... Já tentei algumas coisas como o WordPressSharp e também o JoeBlogs (WordPressWrapper) mas não consigo implementar nenhum deles... O código que ja tenho pega o código html da página e me devolve, por exemplo, o titulo e o conteúdo do "post" em uma variavel ... Só quero saber como faço pra fazer um "auto-post" depois que ele varrer este site... Não sei se deu pra entender.

Comment: Obs: Como disse acima, o título do post seria a variavel TITLE e o post seria HTML

Comment: Se você tentou, poste suas tentativas assim alguém podera te ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que [este projeto no GitHub](https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/JoeBlogs/tree/master/JoeBlogs.Console) em C# (em Console) onde você consegue fazer um post usando a [WordPress XML-RPC interface](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) possa lhe ajudar.

Comment: Sim, mas por exemplo, como se faz isto?Comecei agora em C#...

Comment: @RaulCorreia Assim que tiver um tempo aqui, tentarei postar um exemplo para você.